# CIRC-03 Spin Motor Spin

Tags: motor

I am experimenting with [CIRC-03](http://www.oomlout.com/oom.php/products/ardx/circ-03) but the DC motor won't start spinning with `motorAcceleration();` unless I give it a push. Also, it makes a little noise when it stands still.  It does spin, however, with one of the first two functions (`motorOnThenOff(); motorOnThenOffWithSpeed()`). I've tried adding the 220 µF capacitor but that doesn't change a thing.

Could someone offer me a solution to this problem?

Comment: Where is the code?